# How do I create Json Array in Java8 and only print json if I set value for it?

Tags: java, arrays, json, jackson

I am trying to generate the following using `fasterxml jackson`.. but I am stuck. I can't seem to work out how to create arrays.

```
{
   "setAccId":"12345",
   "groupOf":null,
   "isEnabled":false,
   "list":[
      {
         "student":"jim",
         "type":"S_A",
         "retro":null
      },
      {
         "student":"bob",
         "type":"S_A",
         "retro":null
      }
   ],
   "sort":[]
}
```

I have two classes. One has the Json properties, and the other is where I print it.

> Below class (DynamicJsonHelper) is where I have all the json properties

```
package com.company.jsonfc;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonPropertyOrder;

@JsonPropertyOrder({
"accId",
"groupOf",
"isEnabled"
})

public class DynamicJsonHelper {

    public String accId;
    public String groupOf;
    public List studentList;

    @JsonProperty("accId")
    public void setAccId(String accId) {
        this.accId = accId;
    }

    @JsonProperty("groupOf")
    public void setGroupOf(String groupOf) {
        this.groupOf = groupOf;
    }

    @JsonProperty("isEnabled")
    public boolean isEnabled() {
        return false;
    }

    @JsonProperty("studentList")
    public List<StudentList> studentList() {
        return studentList;
    }

}
```

> Student List Class (as suggested)

```
class StudentList {
    String student;
    String type;
    String retro; 
}
```

> And here is class (PrintJson) where I call it.

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonInclude;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonProcessingException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.node.JsonNodeFactory;

import com.company.jsonfc.DynamicJsonHelper;

@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
public class PrintJson {

    @Test
    public void create_json() throws JsonProcessingException {
    final JsonNodeFactory factory = JsonNodeFactory.instance;

    DynamicJsonHelper dynamicJsonHelper = new DynamicJsonHelper();
    String jsonString;
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

    dynamicJsonHelper.setAccId("12345");

    jsonString = mapper.writeValueAsString(dynamicJsonHelper);
    System.out.println(jsonString);
    }

}
```

> This results in printing the following:

```
{
   "setAccId":"12345",
   "groupOf":null,
   "isEnabled":false
   "studentList":null
}
```

1) How do I add the list:[ ... ] array & the sort: [ ] at the end too?

2) In class PrintJson, I don't set value for `groupOf` but it is still created in Json. How do I set it so if I set value, it is printed.. otherwise it is not included in the json being printed.

**I would appreciate if you took my code and gave me example based on it for better understanding please**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1) How do I add the list:[ ... ] array & the sort: [ ] at the end too?

**Answer**: You can create two more classes one for `list` and one for `sort`. Now in the class `DynamicJsonHelper`  you can add both of them like you have added `accId` or `isEnabled`
and they will be printed. Make sure to add the fields you want in them as instance variables in both of the classes. For example for list you can have a class like:

```
class StudentList{
    String student;
    String type;
    String retro;
}
```

Now add a field in your class `DynamicJsonHelper` as `List<StudentList>`. Similarly you can do for `sort`.

> 2) In class PrintJson, I don't set value for groupOf but it is still
>   created in Json. How do I set it so if I set value, it is printed..
>   otherwise it is not included in the json being printed.

**Answer**: You can **either** use Object mapper and set it to ignore the null fields during serialization. For eg: `mapper.setSerializationInclusion(Include.NON_NULL);`
**Or** you can set it at class level to ignore null values if any. For eg:

```
@JsonInclude(Include.NON_NULL)
class Test
{
  String t;
}
```

As mentioned in the comments by aBnormaLz above doesn't work if the type is primitive like you have for isEnabled. So consider changing it to Boolean and ensure the same for other fields also.

Edit:

```
@JsonPropertyOrder({
"accId",
"groupOf",
"isEnabled"
})
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)

public class DynamicJsonHelper {

public String accId;
public String groupOf;
public List<Student> studentList;

@JsonProperty("accId")
public void setAccId(String accId) {
    this.accId = accId;
}

@JsonProperty("groupOf")
public void setGroupOf(String groupOf) {
    this.groupOf = groupOf;
}

@JsonProperty("isEnabled")
public boolean isEnabled() {
    return false;
}

@JsonProperty("studentList")
public void setStudentList(List<Student> list) {
    this.studentList = list;
}

}

class Student {
private String student;
private String type;
private String retro; 

public Student(String student, String type, String retro) {
    this.student = student;
    this.type = type;
    this.retro = retro;
}

public String getStudent() {
    return student;
}

public void setStudent(String student) {
    this.student = student;
}

public String getType() {
    return type;
}

public void setType(String type) {
    this.type = type;
}

public String getRetro() {
    return retro;
}

public void setRetro(String retro) {
    this.retro = retro;
}    
}

class HelperTest{

public static void main(String[] args) throws JsonProcessingException {
    DynamicJsonHelper dynamicJsonHelper = new DynamicJsonHelper();
    String jsonString;
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

    dynamicJsonHelper.setAccId("12345");

    List<Student> list = Arrays.asList(new Student("s1", "t1", "r1"), new Student("s2", "t2", "r2"));

    dynamicJsonHelper.setStudentList(list);
    jsonString = mapper.writeValueAsString(dynamicJsonHelper);
    System.out.println(jsonString);

}
}
```

After executing the program the `output` is as shown below:

```
{
   "accId": "12345",
   "isEnabled": false,
   "studentList": [
                    {
                      "student": "s1",
                      "type": "t1",
                      "retro": "r1"
                    },
                    {
                      "student": "s2",
                      "type": "t2",
                      "retro": "r2"
                    }
                   ]
}
```

Comment: `Include.NON_NULL` will still print `"isEnabled" :false` since its a primitive boolean. You should also change that to `Boolean`.

Comment: @aBnormaLz thanks for pointing that out. I will edit the answer.

Comment: @aBnormaLz It was `I will edit the answer` which made me miss the upvote. Thanks again :)

Comment: Weeeheeee =) =) Your welcome :) (Also i didn't know that you don't get reputation for comment upvotes :( )

Comment: @Saffik I have added a working piece of code under **Edit** section. Have a look and try to figure out what changes I have made to your code. Post the questions If you have any doubts. And don't worry u don't need to say anything other than ur questions. That's why stackoverflow exists and people are here to answer meaningful questions :)

Answer (score 1):

You missed a point that you have to have third class and it must have property of type java.util.List or array and name list for your example.

e.g.

```
public class JsonHolder {
    // appropriate Json/Jackson annotations ommitted

     private String  setAccId;
     private String  groupOf;
     private boolean isEnabled;
     private List<DynamicJsonHelper>  list;
     private String[] sort;

     // .. getter/setters ...
```

}

then you have to create that object and when you created your DynamicJsonHelper put it into list or array.

After all you can serialize JsonHolder object and you will see your java List or Array as JSON array.

UPD: just note that in JSON structure like `{ ... }` is an object and in Java there must be a class for it.

So, starting with JSON structure you posted

```
{
  "setAccId":"12345",
  "groupOf":null,
  "isEnabled":false,
  "list":[
   {
     "student":"jim",
     "type":"S_A",
     "retro":null
  },
  {
     "student":"bob",
     "type":"S_A",
     "retro":null
  }
 ],
 "sort":[]
}
```

it is an object (let name it `JsonHolder`) with properties named `setAcctId, groupOf, isEnabled, list, sort`
So you have to have a Java class for it (similar as you did for your `DynamicJsonHelper`. You can use any @Json annotations you'd like to the same way (I omitted them and left for you). Even you will not have them Jackson or any other JSON serialiser will use property names in Java class by as default.

I mean as example your @JsonProperty("accId")

```
@JsonProperty("accId")
public void setAccId(String accId)
```

is not required as long as getter/setter/property named also getAcctId, setAcctId, acctId. Jackson will use that if there is no @JsonProperty annotation.

BTW it is better to do it as you did for code readability. :-)

Per your question:
`list` and `sort` properties in JSON are arrays. Jackson parses Java collections classes like List, Set or Arrays to JSON arrays.

Then according to required JSON structure `list` property is a such collection of `DynamicJsonHelper` objects you created. in Java class, List or Array is just your choice - use what is more suitable for you. I recommend to use a List rather than Array. Work with arrays in Java is not a good idea. :-)

So far you just created a Java class `DynamicJsonHelper` only for objects which must be in `list` property of `JsonHolder` object. What's left is to create that "JsonHolder" class and give that object to Jackson to serialize it into required JSON structure.

There are bunch of @Json annotations you can use to allow or not `null` or empty values, change property names, exclude Java class properties to be serialized and so, and so... All is up to you... good luck!